# Can't parse json correctly

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

need help in parsing this json file from this endpoint

http://ergast.com/api/f1/constructors

this is my data class

```
data class Teams(
val MRData: MRdata
){
    data class MRdata(
        val ConstructorTable: ConstructorsTable,
        val limit: String,
        val offset: String,
        val series: String,
        val total: String,
        val url: String,
        val xmlns: String
    ){
        data class ConstructorsTable(
            val Constructors: List<Constructor>?
            ) {
            data class Constructor(
                val constructorId: String?,
                val name: String?,
                val nationality: String?,
                val url: String?
        )
    }
}
}
```

when i use Teams class as a return model it logs actual data but, when i try to return specific data like constructorID or nationality it returns null.

Comment: I do not see a `JSON` formatted output on the linked endpoint, its a table. You'll need to implement a different logic to parse that output.

Comment: i tried with liveData and it works now. i don't know why. had everything same with flow and wasn't working. now with livedata it works. strange. thanks anyways!

Comment: That is not JSON, it is an HTML website.

Comment: yes i know, but when you append .json? in the end of any call it responds with json